# How to do an array in a cURL POST request from the command line

Tags: arrays, json, curl, http-post

I am trying to send a POST request given the following requirements.

Guidelines

The content type for the submission should be application/json

The following is the structure of the body:

Name: String

PhoneNumber: String

Email: String

Position: String

Urls: Array of objects containing the following properties

Type: String

Link: String

All fields are required.
At least one URL with the "Resume" type is required

If your submission was successful, you will receive a HTTP 202 response

I believe my syntax is correct for sending the data in JSON.

I am having trouble with correctly coding the array.

My code so far:

```
curl -g -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:
     application/json" -X POST -d '{"Name":"data", 
     "PhoneNumber":"data", "Email":"data@gmail.com", 
     "Position":"data", "Url[]=GitHub", 
     "Url[]=github.com/data", "Url[]=Resume", 
     "Url[]=linkedin.com/in/data"}' 
     https://example
```

Here are the errors I am receiving:

```
curl: (3) Port number out of range
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: gmail.com
curl: (3) Illegal port number
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: url[]=Github,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: url[]=github.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: url[]=Resume,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: url[]=linkedin.com
```

Any help will be appreciated and please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off putting the data in a file and calling it (e.g. data.json, calling that with -d @data.json).

Otherwise you need to escape your double quotes that are inside.